# How to make FileInputStream read() function stop after having read a certain byte?

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to create a program which compresses and saves the bytes of files into a .txt file for decompression. So far, I've been succesful only saving the bytes of one file to the .txt file. However, when saving multiple files, I can't find a way to let the program know which bytes belong to which file. How can I instruct the program to stop reading the bytes when it encounters the bytes of the next program? My compress function:

```
private void compress(File source, File destination) {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination, true));
        int len;
        while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(len);
            gzip.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        gzip.finish();
        gzip.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File couldn't be located. Please check the path given.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my decompress function:

```
 private byte[] decompress(File source) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));
        int len;
        while ((len = gzip.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        gzip.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File couldn't be located. Please check the path given.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried adding "START" before and "END" after any byte group, to use substring to pick the needed bytes, but after converting back to bytes, the decompressed file will be corrupted. I would abstain from using zip, because i want to create my own archives.

Comment: The gzip format is such that you can detect the original file boundaries, but I’m not sure if the Java implementation does this: most implementations just concatenate the decompressed output as a single file. If it doesn’t, you could wrap the input in a filter that finds these boundaries yourself, paring some of the gzip header and footer information. But at that point, it would be easier and perhaps more useful just to use the zip format.

Comment: If you want to write your own format (why?), when reading the gzip, wrap the file input stream in your own extension of `FilterInputStream` that searches for your end-of-file marker. And the end of file marker is “endstart” between chunks and “end”-EOF at the end of the archive. There’s a high chance of seeing a short token like “end” anywhere in the compressed output.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll keep your suggestions in mind. One thing though, I changed to the Deflater class instead of the Gzip one, keeping the very same methods, since it's slightly better in terms of compression. Do I have to create the file and archive markers myself? If so, what should I use, since Strings won't do the job?